# Android ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION for app running on Android 8 but targeting Android 11(API 30)

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

My Target Api is 30.
I have declared below permissions in my manifest, following this code-lab example(https://developer.android.com/codelabs/activity-recognition-transition#2):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
```

With this,
1] when my app is running on Android 10 and above, I am able to ask for a ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission and it also returns true if I check in my code, like:

```
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireContext(),
            Manifest.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

2] But the same code always returns false, when my app is running on phone with Android 8(below 10) and I also don't see physical activity under permissions list in App settings.

Questions:
Since I am targeting Android API 30, should I not use > "android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" in manifest? If yes,then will it grant permission when my app runs on phone with Android 8?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is what the Android documentation says for ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission.**

If your app targets Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, the system auto-grants the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission to your app, as needed, if your app satisfies each of the following conditions:

1. The manifest file includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission.
2. The manifest file doesn't include the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission.
   If the system-auto grants the android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION permission, your app retains the permission after you update your app to target Android 10. However, the user can revoke this permission at any time in system settings.*

**Basically don't ask for this permission below Android 10 at runtime, just add it in manifest**

Comment: I am targeting API 30; My question is in codelab it says to include both the permission(pls see the link attached in the question). Which is basically contradicting with the snippet you pasted from docs.
Let's say, If I am targeting API 30 and my app runs on mobile with Android 8, would it auto-grant the permission, just by having  android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Got the same problem